# Behaviour subject inside the form group (as control)

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I have a form group named `currentForm` with a form array named items.
Due to applications component's issues I need to have a subject inside the item form group and I'm not sure if it's good practice.

```
let item = this.fb.group({
      myListAsSubject: [new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([])]
    });
```

Is this a safe solution? What should I watch out for?

Comment: It may be that you have [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, could you please provide more details about the problem you're trying to solve by using BehaviorSubject as a formControl value?

Comment: Showing us a standalone component (html and typescript) of what you are doing might be able to allow us to help you better. Also a version of angular might be helpful in this case since there has be big strides in the last two versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using behavior subject is not a common practice. There can be some issues which arise from it. Such as complexity which makes your code hard to understand . Another example is where you need to patch values of `myListAsSubject`, it would not be able to update the value as a form control and would require additional logic